# tail command showing log file contents in non-real time

Tags: c++, logging, io-redirection, tail, solaris-10

I have a C++ application (on Solaris 10) that shows log output based on the time chronological transactions. For example, before establishing a connection to Database server, it prints in stdout as: "Connecting to DB" and after the call to connect, if successful, says "Connected to DB", if failed, says, "failed to connect to DB" and so on. 
Now, when the application is run, the output (stdout) gets redirected to a log file as below:

```
appl > app.log
```

And, on another session, to see what's going on, I view as:

```
tail -f app.log
```

`tail -f` command is supposed to run in an endless loop, sleeping for a second and then attempt to read and copy lines from app.log and show on console. This helps to monitor what's going on in app.log
While I see the ordering of outputs maintained, I see that sometimes outputs are coming many lines together as a chunk and then waiting, and it's not in real-time as things are happening. Is it because of the sleep and pull behavior of tail -f? Please help me to understand why it is not in real time. Or is there any other way to get a feel of real time?

Comment: When you output to the log are you flushing the buffer each time with `std::endl` or `std::flush`?

Comment: Yes, it's like std::cout << "some log" << std::endl; And std::endl flushes the output, in fact if not redirected to app.log, it shows just fine, but when redirected and viewed from another session through tail -f the perception problem appears

Comment: Besides the delays in `tail` reading from the file (which certainly is an issue), there may also be delays in the OS actually writing to the file. It's not only the output from the program that is buffered, the operating system also have buffers when writing files to disk (and then the hardware has buffers as well). All this buffering could mean that data is not actually written to the disk immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the watch command on this file with an interval of 5 seconds and see if its having the same behavior as tail. If the write to the file app.log is missing in real-time similar will be the output in tail.