# tail and less commands not monitoring file in real time

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm looking for a way to monitor a file that is written to by a program on Linux. I found the `tail -F` command in [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1669/shell-command-to-monitor-changes-in-a-file-whats-it-called-again), and also recommended was `less +FG`. I tested it by running `tail -F file` in one terminal, and a simple python script:

```
import time

for i in range(20):
  print i
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

in another. I redirected the output to the file:

```
python script.py >> file
```

I expected that `tail` would track the file contents and update the display in fixed intervals, instead it only shows what was written to the file *after* the command terminates.

The same thing happens with `less +FG` and also if I watch the output from `cat`. I've also tried using the usual redirect which truncates the file `>` instead of `>>`. Here it says the file was truncated, but still does not track it in real time.

Any idea why this doesn't work? (It's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166123/tail-command-showing-log-file-contents-in-non-real-time) that it might be due to buffered writes, but since my script runs over 10 seconds, I suspect this might not be the cause)

Edit: In case it matters, I'm running Linux Mint 18.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's standard out is buffered. If when you close the script / script is done, you see all the output - that's definitely buffer issue.

You can use this instead:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(20):
    sys.stdout.write('%d\n' % i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I've tested it and it prints values in real time. To overcome buffer issue, after each `.write()` method I use `.flush()` force "flushing" the buffer.

---

**Additional options from the comments:**

- Use the original `print` statement with `sys.stdout.flush()` afterwords
- Run the python script with `python -u` for unbuffered binary stdout and stderr

Comment: Probaly you want `sys.stdout.write('%d\n' % i)`, or the equivalent, since the original used `print` which includes newlines.

Comment: @larsks thanks for commenting, I fixed it in my answer

Comment: You can leave it as `print` and still use `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Comment: @DavisHerring nice, I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: You can also run the original script (without `sys.stdout.flush()`) with `python -u` to turn off buffering altogether.

Comment: So this was indeed the problem. Is there any way to force unbuffered writes for output from any command(that doesn't involve changing the code)? Thanks!

Comment: @NILobachevsky you can try running the script with `python -u`

Comment: @Vinny I meant not specific to Python. Is there an environment variable or something that will force unbuffered writes no matter what program is used?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

Regarding jon1467 answer (sorry can't comment your answer), your understanding of redirection is wrong.

Try this :

```
dd if=/dev/urandom > test.txt
```

while looking at the file size with :

```
ls -l test.txt
```

You'll see the file grow while dd is running.

Vinny's answer is correct, python standard output is buffered.
The more common way to the "buffering effect" you notice is by flushing the stdout as Vinny showed you.

You could also use `-u` option to disable buffering for the whole python process, or you could just reopen standard output with a buffer size of 0 as below (in python2 at least):

```
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
```